# How to save data from dynamically created edittext at runtime to sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext

I am building a program that creates 6 edit Text at run-time and I want to save the data input by the user in those edittexts into sqlite Database but I'm getting an error. and i provided the code that is creating my edit texts i hope i can get some help please. the error is in the second case.

```
the edittext is may have not been initialized.



    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonAddIntervention:

                final TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableinterventions);

                EditText ed = new EditText(this);
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                final TableRow tabr = new TableRow(this);
                tabr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv.setText("Code");
                ed.setHint("Code");
                ed.setText("", null);
                ed.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tabr.addView(tv);
                tabr.addView(ed);
                table.addView(tabr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                EditText ed1 = new EditText(this);
                TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
                Button b1 = new Button(this);
                final TableRow tabr1 = new TableRow(this);
                tabr1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                b1.setText("-");
                tv1.setText("Start Time");
                ed1.setHint("Start Time");
                ed1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                b1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tabr1.addView(tv1);
                tabr1.addView(ed1);
                tabr1.addView(b1);
                table.addView(tabr1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));




                EditText ed2 = new EditText(this);
                TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
                final TableRow tabr2 = new TableRow(this);
                tabr2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv2.setText("End Time");
                ed2.setHint("End Time");
                ed2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tabr2.addView(tv2);
                tabr2.addView(ed2);
                table.addView(tabr2, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) );

                EditText ed3 = new EditText(this);
                TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
                final TableRow tabr3 = new TableRow(this);
                tabr3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv3.setText("Description");
                ed3.setHint("Description");
                ed3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tabr3.addView(tv3);
                tabr3.addView(ed3);
                table.addView(tabr3,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                EditText ed4 = new EditText(this);
                TextView tv4 = new TextView(this);
                final TableRow tabr4 = new TableRow(this);
                tabr4.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv4.setText("Product");
                ed4.setHint("Product");
                ed4.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv4.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tabr4.addView(tv4);
                tabr4.addView(ed4);
                table.addView(tabr4,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                EditText ed5 = new EditText(this);
                TextView tv5 = new TextView(this);
                final TableRow tabr5 = new TableRow(this);
                tabr5.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv5.setText("Serial Number");
                ed5.setHint("Serial Number");
                ed5.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(190,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv5.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tabr5.addView(tv5);
                tabr5.addView(ed5);
                table.addView(tabr5,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        table.removeView(tabr);
                        table.removeView(tabr1);
                        table.removeView(tabr2);
                        table.removeView(tabr3);
                        table.removeView(tabr4);
                        table.removeView(tabr5);


                    }

                });
                break;

case R.id.BtnTestSaveAll:

            InterventionsDatabase idb1 = new InterventionsDatabase();


        //the error is here the ed,ed1,ed2,ed3,ed4 and ed5 may not have been initialized
            String cod= String.valueOf(ed.getText());
            String s_time = String.valueOf(ed1.getText().toString());
            String e_time = String.valueOf(ed2.getText().toString());
            String d = String.valueOf(ed3.getText().toString());
            String p = String.valueOf(ed4.getText().toString());
            String Sn = String.valueOf(ed5.getText().toString());


            idb1.setEmp_code(Integer.parseInt(cod));
            idb1.setEmp_startTime(Integer.parseInt(s_time));
            idb1.setEmp_endTime(Integer.parseInt(e_time));
            idb1.setDescription(d);
            idb1.setProduct(p);
            idb1.setSerialNumber(Integer.parseInt(Sn));

            Dbhelper.createInterventionsDB(Integer.parseInt(cod),Integer.parseInt(s_time),Integer.parseInt(e_time), d, p,Integer.parseInt(Sn));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yeah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
```

Comment: Please post relevant code and the error(s) you're getting.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: how can i post the code here?

Comment: where is code of edittext

Comment: wait till i post the code please

Comment: i posted the code where i am having the error

Comment: can anyone check the code now please?

Comment: in the above code im getting no errors but when i am trying to get the values of those edit texts it will underline it with a red line and when i move the mouse on it it will say may have not been initialized.

Comment: @Jadballout I just posted answer for your question... you're initializing `EditText` in `Button`'s `onClick()` (therefore when the button is clicked) and your probably want to access it somewhere else. Compiler prevents from this, because it must be sure that `EditText` is initialized, it can't rely on user to click the button.

Comment: i added the full code finally i specified where is the error, in the first case i'm creating the dynamic edit texts and in the second case i'm trying to save their values to the database

Comment: @PiotrChojnacki then how can i do this? because i have to save those values to the database

Comment: @Jadballout I updated my answer, tell me if it's clear now or if I should try to explain it more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

The "may have not been initialized" error appears when you want to access object which... may have not been initialized. It means that for example this code won't work:

```
int a = 5;
EditText et;

if(a == 5) {
   et = new EditText();
}

et.setText("some text");
```

It won't work, because `et` is initialized inside `if` statement, which condition in this case of course is passed, but the compiler doesn't know that. It's just more safe to show you that you made a mistake here than eventually having your application crashed on run-time.

Edit:

You're initializing `EditText` in `Button`'s `onClick()` (therefore when the `Button` is clicked) and you want to access it somewhere else (when the other `Button` is clicked). Compiler prevents this, because it must be sure that EditText is initialized, it can't rely on user to click the initializing button first.

In order to solve this problem, create those `EditText`'s to be fields of your `Activity` class and initialize them in `onCreate()`, there's no need to do this when the `Button` is clicked. And that's it.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked as @laalto just said :) but thanks for the help its so kind of you guys :)

Comment: @Jadballout You're welcome! Consider accepting the answer which was most helpful for you.

Comment: Yes but thanks a lot i mean it.But i guess he got what i meant directly because i didn't know how to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Construct like this:

```
switch (var) {
  case 1:
    SomeType foo = new SomeType();
    // ...
    break;

  case 2:
    foo.something();
    // ...
    break;
}
```

has the problem that `foo` is not initialized when `case 2` is executing. Variables are visible in their declaring curly `{}` scope, i.e. the `switch` in this case. However, the code execution path, when case 2 is taken, doesn't include the initialization of the variable. The compiler is smart enough to notice this and gives you a warning.

In your case a good solution is to move the `EditText` variable declarations to class member level:

```
private EditText mEd1;

// ...

    mEd1 = new EditText(this);
```

and when referencing them, check for non-null

```
if (mEd1 != null) {
   // ...
   String s_time = String.valueOf(mEd1.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get view of all edittext first then do whatever you want something like this:

```
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.your_layout);
for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
    View view = group.getChildAt(i);
    if (view instanceof EditText) {
        ((EditText)view).setText("");
    }
}
```